# ggplot hex color is different than latex hex color on pdf when knitting with rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, r-markdown

When creating a plot in ggplot using a particular hexcode for a fill color and also using the same hexcode in latex for styling, the colors come out slightly different in the PDF.

The latex creates a very close color to the hex, while the ggplot is farther off.

Latex is #1360AA
ggplot is #145FAA

The desired hex color is #1260AA

Color_Issue.Rmd

````
---
documentclass: scrreprt
classoption: a4paper
fontsize: 11pt
params: 
   set_title: "Bug"
output: 
  pdf_document:
     includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---

\fboxsep=4cm
\fcolorbox{sblue}{sblue}{\null}

```{r box, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)


df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2),
  y = c(2, 2))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(), fill = "#1260AA")
```
````

preamble.tex

```
    \usepackage{xcolor} \definecolor{sblue}{HTML}{1260AA}
```

How can I ensure the same colors across the languages in the PDF?